# Why can't I download the pdf using this code?

Tags: python, pdf, beautifulsoup, valueerror

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlretrieve

url='https://www.go100.com.tw/exam_download_3.php'
response = requests.get(url)
response.encoding = 'utf-8'

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
#print(soup)
all_as = soup.find_all('a')

for index, a_tag in enumerate(all_as):
    if 'pdf' in a_tag['href']:  
        #print(a_tag['href'])
        urlretrieve(a_tag['href'], 'file_tmp.pdf')
        break
```

It shows ValueError, and I can't find what's wrong.[here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IWHa.png)

Comment: [You should not post code (or error/exception messages, data etc.) as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14311263). Add the error as text in a code block.

Answer (score 0):

You've already done 90% of the work. You must use `urljoin` from `urllib.parse`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

url='https://www.go100.com.tw/exam_download_3.php'
response = requests.get(url)
response.encoding = 'utf-8'

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
#print(soup)
all_as = soup.find_all('a')

for index, a_tag in enumerate(all_as):
    if 'pdf' in a_tag['href']:  
        print(a_tag['href'])
        print(urljoin(url, a_tag['href']))
        response = requests.get(urljoin(url, a_tag['href']))
        open("file_tmp.pdf", "wb").write(response.content)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download all those files using requests only:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url='https://www.go100.com.tw/exam_download_3.php'

s = requests.Session()

correct_links = []
r = s.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
links = [a.get('href') for a in soup.select('a') if '.pdf' in a.get('href')]
for link in links:
    if 'https://' not in link:
        link = 'https://www.go100.com.tw' + link
    correct_links.append(link)
for link in list(set(correct_links)):
    r = s.get(link)
    with open(f"{re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '', link)}.pdf", "wb") as f:
        f.write(r.content)
        print(f"saved {re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '', link)}")
```

This will save all the downloadable pdfs in the same folder where you are running the script from, with relevant names.
Requests documentation: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/